# My system runs out of available disk space due to logs as i am using IBM Info-sphere Datastage Designer Client

Tags: websphere, etl, datastage, ibm-infosphere

How can i delete/import the logs to free up disk space "Drive C" as i am using IBM Info-sphere Data-stage Designer Client or how can i import these logs file to Drive D?

Comment: The issue has been resolved i found out that there was an Increase replication factor for __consumer_offsets Kafka(C:\IBM\InformationServer\shared-open-source\kafka\data\1\__consumer_offsets-0) so i just had to move that from Drive C: to Drive D: by creating a same server1 file in the drive and changing its path to Drive D: and its new folder ... restart the server again and Voila! Done and Dusted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are being written to your Temp folder you could change the TEMP environment variable to point to a suitable folder on the D: drive.